# Javascript Alert Box flashes but does not stop at the OK button?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner at JavaScript.
I've read that when an alert box pops up, the user will have to click "OK" to proceed.
However, this [Alert Box Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z3dp5s0b/1/) (jsfiddle) does not stop at OK?

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick='alert(window.location="https://www.google.com");'>Google</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm), which prompts for user confirmation, instead of `alert`:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var confirmed = confirm("Redirect?");
  if(confirmed){
    window.location="https://www.google.com";
  }
})
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button>Google</button>
</body>

</html>
```